# Definitions made in $HOME/.XCompose file do not work in Firefox (snap)

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, xorg, 22.10

I have made some **MultiKey** definitions in my [.XCompose](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/XCompose.5.html) file named `$HOME/.XCompose`. Basically the file contains the following:

```
<Multi_key> <T> <L> : "₺"   U20ba   # TURKISH LIRA SIGN
<Multi_key> <t> <l> : "₺"   U20ba   # TURKISH LIRA SIGN
```

I have restarted my desktop session and it seems that my definitions work on all applications that I have tested so far, with one exception being **FireFox**. I guess the reason is that FireFox is installed as a snap in my desktop Ubuntu 22.10 system.

Generally asking, how can I make a snap application use the `$HOME/.XCompose` file?

Comment: You can install FF as a deb instead of snap.

Comment: Yes. But I would like to address the problem for any snap application (in the future).

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible.

Comment: @nteodosio Yesterday I was trying to use the same solution, but it was not working. Today it seems that it works. Probably, it is related to restarting my system; I don't know. Thank you BTW.